# How to find out which Firefox extension prints to console

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, firefox-developer-tools

One of the Firefox extensions I installed prints 'undefined' to the console. It happens in a file cs.js. Is there any way to find out which extension does that, apart from disabling them one by one?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, in newer versions of Firefox logs from extensions are normally not shown within the console anymore because that's normally a bug and some of those got fixed in the past.

Though in case you still see a log message coming from a source you don't know, hovering over the source link (in your case 'cs.js') will show you the full URL of the file. And you can click it to see it within the Debugger or open it in a separate tab. If it's really coming from an extension, then the URL will start with `moz-extension://`.

And in order to know which extension it is, go to `about:debugging#/runtime/this-firefox`. There you'll see a list of all your installed extensions, and for each extension its "Internal UUID".

[image: List of Firefox extensions including their internal UUIDs]

Compare the one of your message with the ones in that list and you'll find out which extension it is.